# Is there a primer/help/reference for Elementary OS Calendar?

Tags: release-hera, calendar

I decided to try Calendar as home base for mail.com calDAV, but I'm having trouble at the lowest level, even creating events manually. I am so not getting it. I've used generations of Outlook, iCal, and deprecated competitors, not a rookie, but whatever is happening with Calendar design is so foreign to me I'm just spinning my wheels and getting frustrated. If I need to ask one specific detail at a time here, I can.

Comment: As near as I can tell, you double-click to add new stuff. You click on the gear icon, add new calendar, and use the drop down to add a calendar from Google or CalDAV. That's about it, really. I just use the calendaring extension with Thunderbird.

Comment: Fair enough, but those are three things that I'll have to address individually, as none, for me, are working as expected. No primer?

Comment: Not that I've found. I'm mostly a Lubuntu user that has started helping out over here because so few questions get answered. You can check [here](https://github.com/elementary/calendar) but they make no mention of a detailed online manual of any sorts.

Comment: git didn't seem helpful. This is looking like a dead end so I'm going to start discrete feature questions. I'll leave this open here for a while, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll shut this down:

There is no primer/help/reference for Elementary OS Calendar.